# How is the __func__ identifier a security risk?

Tags: c, security, macros

I saw in a comment that using `__func__` is a security risk. I need to understand how is that the case?

Comment: Short answer: Someone wrote something stupid in a comment. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `__func__` reveals the function name in the binary, which ease the work of an attacker that has an access to the binary.

Comment: But what does knowing a function name do? How does it help an attacker if he knows the name of a function?

Comment: if the function name is sha256, aes_decrypt or get_secret_key, I assume it might help him.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet If a key is on untrusted systems, it is by definition not secret.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I think there are more and less secure system, I am not aware of any system that is absolutely secure, and I think revealing the function name makes it less secure. And "get_secret_key" was just an example.

Comment: Finding an AES implementation doesn't sound that hard, unless white-box crypto techniques were applied. In the trivial case just use FLIRT or a similar function finder, in more difficult cases look for the AES S-Boxes or AES-NI instructions. From there to the key it's typically a small step.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - again, just examples. The information erasure of the compiler/linker may be a pain, but is an advantage when analyzing code. __func__ may be a great shortcut.

Comment: My point is that if the security of your application depends on the application being hard to analyze, the application is broken in the first place.

Comment: I still can't understand how knowing a function name makes your program less secure. "Easier to crack" and "less secure" are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It makes reverse engineering easier. So if you want to keep the way your application works secret, then it makes an attacker's life easier.

That's relevant for DRM features, or if you want to make it harder to imitate your algorithms in competing applications.

But it does not affect security, since an application where reversing shows vulnerabilities was insecure in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If your application's security relies on its function names remaining a secret then it is a security risk to use `__func__`, as the compiler will need to store the function name somewhere in the compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

`__func__` is the C99-standard predefined identifier that expands into a character array variable containing the function name when it is used inside of a function. From C99 6.4.2.2/1 describes:

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as
>   if, immediately following the opening brace of each function
>   definition, the declaration
>
> static const char `__func__`[] = "function-name"; appeared, where
>   function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function. This
>   name is the unadorned name of the function.

Note that it is not a macro and it has no special meaning during preprocessing.

Look at this link for more information about `__func__` at: 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1642.html

If the solution relies on the expansion involved in the predefined context-sensitive constant  `__func__`, it cannot be implemented in a function safely and provide the same convenience.

`__func__` is textually expanded at the point of its invocation, hence, it could easily affect the flow of control of the invoking code by evaluating break, continue, or return statements or failing to properly terminate if statements. The effects of invoking it can be surprising and lead to subtle flaws.

Prefer inline or static functions to function-like macros or `__func__`.

However, in cases where defining a `__func__` is unavoidable, the definition should avoid statements that change the control flow of the invoking code.And ideally, it should be a single expression.

More idea and example codes:
 https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE13-C.+Avoid+changing+control+flow+in+macro+definitions

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question, which is specifically about the _security risks_ and not the general operation/implementation of `__func__`.

Comment: I tried making the use of  `__func__` more understandable and the fact that its not a `macro` as OP says in the question. "The effects of invoking it can be surprising and lead to subtle flaws." and the links given in the answer very well point to how it can cause other dependent modules to behave unpredictably and hence less securely.